# make wget download a file directly to disk from bash

Tags: wget

On a website, after logging in with my credentials I am able to download daa by changing the url address to variations of this:

```
https://data.somewhere.com/DataDownload/getfile.jsp?ccy=AUDUSD&df=BBO&year=2014&month=02&dllater=Download
```

This put a zip file in my downlaod directory.

If I try to automate it with wget using:

```
wget "https://data.somewhere.com/DataDownload/getfile.jsp?ccy=AUDUSD&df=BBO&year=2014&month=02&dllater=Download" --no-check-certificate --ignore-length
```

$ ~/dnloadHotSpot.sh

```
--2014-03-22 16:05:16--  https://data.somewhere.com/DataDownload/getfile.jsp?ccy=AUDUSD&df=BBO&year=2014&month=02&dllater=Download
Resolving data.somewhere.com (data.somewhere.com)... 209.191.250.173
Connecting to data.somewhere.com (data.somewhere.com)|209.191.250.173|:443... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK
Length: ignored [text/html]
Saving to: `getfile.jsp@ccy=AUDUSD&df=BBO&year=2014&month=02&dllater=Download'

    [ <=>                                                                                                                                                               ] 8,925       --.-K/s   in 0.001s

2014-03-22 16:05:18 (14.4 MB/s) - `getfile.jsp@ccy=AUDUSD&df=BBO&year=2014&month=02&dllater=Download' saved [8925]
```

What else to I need to add to make wget actually download the file?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to specify the name of the output file into which wget places the contents of the file is is downloading, then use the capital O parameter, something like:

```
wget -O myfilename ......
```

Comment: But this url link causes a download - it is not the web content I want. Or am I using it wrong?